# OpenGL ES 1.0: Hide texture parts while textures overlapped

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures

I have a texture for road. Line (represented by triangle strips) with this texture looks like this:
[image: road1]

And of course, roads can be overlapped by other roads. In this case I want to hide road borders. Road borders has alpha 0.6 in same time as road has alpha 1. So how I can hide texture parts with less alpha when they overlapped by texture parts with greater alpha?
Here's what I have:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpXVW.png]

And this is what I want:

[image: road2]

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any function of the alpha channel that can do compare like that.

What I might do:

1. Enable alpha test to reject alpha<0.8 (don't want to draw border yet)
2. Draw your texture at some fixed depth, this should draw the main yellow road only.
3. Disable the alpha test
4. Enable depth test
5. Redraw the road again at some larger depth value. This pass will draw the road borders, but any place where the main road is already drawn will be depth rejected.
6. You should be left with a result similar to your desired image.

Alternatively you could use the stencil buffer in the same way, but depth test is probably easier to set up.